# How to add additional req.body properties to actual post request and then redirect it in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, url-routing

I run into situation, when i have a feeling, that I'm missing something really obvious...

On client side sits form, that submits to, lets say `/submit`

on server side I handle it with:

```
app.post('/submit', function (req, res) {

    'use strict';
    res.redirect(307, "https://ssl.example.com");
});
```

Everything works, but problem is - I need to add additional data to that post message, that i dont want show to user with hidden inputs.

if I add to that function, lets say

```
req.body.newthing = "hey, i'm new here!"
```

its not visible on destination  host.

i guess, that express redirect (probably as it should) don't care about what i do to req.body and redirects exactly what client posted.

My question is - is it possible to alter/add req.body, and then redirect client post request  to another host as post request?

Comment: did i understand correct, you want to get a post from a client and redirect to an other server? on the same domain or an other? and why would you need this?

Comment: should the new post come from the first(nodejs) server, or from the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to alter the client's POST request when redirecting in this way, unless of course you want to proxy the request by having the server do the redirect on the client's behalf.

Comment: thanks for confirming my worries. I dont want to proxy that request, so i have to stick with hidden values and some additional js on client side to set up few things :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `express-session` middleware. To learn more about it, go to https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html.

Comment: Please, consider adding some code examples.